# How to set the skin of a DotNetNuke page through code?

Tags: api, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I'm working on a DNN module that creates DNN pages (tabs) and places DNN modules on them through code.  So, far that's working very well.  However, I'd like it to also be able to programmatically set the page's skin and place the modules in the appropriate pane.

Does anyone know how to do this using code?

---

**Solution:**

I set **SkinSrc** and **ContainerSrc** as [mika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13460/mika) suggested.

Here's my source, if you're interested.  This is where I set **SkinSrc**.

```
''' <summary>Create new DNN tab/page.</summary>
        Private Function CreatePage(ByVal ParentID As Integer, ByVal PageName As String, ByVal PageTitle As String, ByVal Description As String, ByVal Keywords As String, ByVal Permissions As TabPermissionCollection, Optional ByVal SkinSrc As String = "", Optional ByVal isVisible As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal LoadDefaultModules As Boolean = True) As Tabs.TabInfo
            Try
                Dim tabCtrlr As New TabController
                Dim newTab As New Tabs.TabInfo
                Dim newPermissions As TabPermissionCollection = newTab.TabPermissions
                Dim permissionProvider As PermissionProvider = permissionProvider.Instance
                Dim infPermission As TabPermissionInfo

                ' set new page properties
                newTab.PortalID = PortalId
                newTab.TabName = PageName
                newTab.Title = PageTitle
                newTab.Description = Description
                newTab.KeyWords = Keywords
                newTab.IsDeleted = False
                newTab.IsSuperTab = False
                newTab.IsVisible = isVisible
                newTab.DisableLink = False
                newTab.IconFile = ""
                newTab.Url = ""
                newTab.ParentId = ParentID

                'add skinsrc if specified
                If (SkinSrc.Length > 0) Then newTab.SkinSrc = SkinSrc

                ' create new page
                tabCtrlr.AddTab(newTab, LoadDefaultModules)

                ' copy permissions selected in Permissions collection
                For index As Integer = 0 To (Permissions.Count - 1)
                    infPermission = New TabPermissionInfo

                    infPermission.AllowAccess = Permissions(index).AllowAccess
                    infPermission.RoleID = Permissions(index).RoleID
                    infPermission.RoleName = Permissions(index).RoleName
                    infPermission.TabID = Permissions(index).TabID
                    infPermission.PermissionID = Permissions(index).PermissionID

                    'save permission info
                    newPermissions.Add(infPermission, True)
                    permissionProvider.SaveTabPermissions(newTab)
                Next index

                'return TabInfo of new page
                Return newTab

            Catch ex As Exception
                'failure
                Return New Tabs.TabInfo
            End Try
        End Function
```

These next two functions were taken from the DNN source and tweaked slightly, so I can't take credit for much of them.  Also, if you use these in your own modules there could be issues when upgrading DNN.  Although the upgrade from 5.05 to 5.06 went smoothly for me.

In the **AddNewModule** function, I used **ContainerSrc** to specify the custom container to use.  **PaneName** is the property used to specify which panel the module should be placed in.

```
#Region "From DNN Source --mostly"

#Region "Enums"

        Private Enum ViewPermissionType
            View = 0
            Edit = 1
        End Enum

#End Region

        ''' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>Adds a New Module to a Pane</summary>
        ''' <param name="align">The alignment for the Module</param>
        ''' <param name="desktopModuleId">The Id of the DesktopModule</param>
        ''' <param name="permissionType">The View Permission Type for the Module</param>
        ''' <param name="title">The Title for the resulting module</param>
        ''' <param name="paneName">The pane to add the module to</param>
        ''' <param name="position">The relative position within the pane for the module</param>
        ''' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Private Function AddNewModule(ByVal TabID As Integer, ByVal title As String, ByVal desktopModuleId As Integer, ByVal paneName As String, ByVal position As Integer, ByVal permissionType As ViewPermissionType, ByVal align As String) As Integer

            Dim objTabController As New TabController
            Dim objTabPermissions As TabPermissionCollection = objTabController.GetTab(TabID, PortalId, True).TabPermissions
            Dim objPermissionController As New PermissionController
            Dim objModules As New ModuleController
            Dim objModuleDefinition As ModuleDefinitionInfo
            Dim objEventLog As New Services.Log.EventLog.EventLogController
            Dim newModuleID As Integer
            Dim j As Integer

            Try
                Dim desktopModule As DesktopModuleInfo = Nothing
                If Not DesktopModuleController.GetDesktopModules(PortalSettings.PortalId).TryGetValue(desktopModuleId, desktopModule) Then
                    Throw New ArgumentException("desktopModuleId")
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                LogException(ex)
            End Try

            Dim UserId As Integer = -1
            If Request.IsAuthenticated Then
                Dim objUserInfo As Users.UserInfo = UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo
                UserId = objUserInfo.UserID
            End If

            For Each objModuleDefinition In ModuleDefinitionController.GetModuleDefinitionsByDesktopModuleID(desktopModuleId).Values
                Dim objModule As New ModuleInfo
                objModule.Initialize(PortalSettings.PortalId)

                objModule.PortalID = PortalSettings.PortalId
                objModule.TabID = TabID
                objModule.ModuleOrder = position
                If title = "" Then
                    objModule.ModuleTitle = objModuleDefinition.FriendlyName
                Else
                    objModule.ModuleTitle = title
                End If
                objModule.PaneName = paneName
                objModule.ModuleDefID = objModuleDefinition.ModuleDefID
                If objModuleDefinition.DefaultCacheTime > 0 Then
                    objModule.CacheTime = objModuleDefinition.DefaultCacheTime
                    If Portals.PortalSettings.Current.DefaultModuleId > Null.NullInteger AndAlso Portals.PortalSettings.Current.DefaultTabId > Null.NullInteger Then
                        Dim defaultModule As ModuleInfo = objModules.GetModule(Portals.PortalSettings.Current.DefaultModuleId, Portals.PortalSettings.Current.DefaultTabId, True)
                        If Not defaultModule Is Nothing Then
                            objModule.CacheTime = defaultModule.CacheTime
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

                Select Case permissionType
                    Case ViewPermissionType.View
                        objModule.InheritViewPermissions = True
                    Case ViewPermissionType.Edit
                        objModule.InheritViewPermissions = False
                End Select

                ' get the default module view permissions
                Dim arrSystemModuleViewPermissions As ArrayList = objPermissionController.GetPermissionByCodeAndKey("SYSTEM_MODULE_DEFINITION", "VIEW")

                ' get the permissions from the page
                For Each objTabPermission As TabPermissionInfo In objTabPermissions
                    If objTabPermission.PermissionKey = "VIEW" AndAlso permissionType = ViewPermissionType.View Then
                        'Don't need to explicitly add View permisisons if "Same As Page"
                        Continue For
                    End If

                    ' get the system module permissions for the permissionkey
                    Dim arrSystemModulePermissions As ArrayList = objPermissionController.GetPermissionByCodeAndKey("SYSTEM_MODULE_DEFINITION", objTabPermission.PermissionKey)
                    ' loop through the system module permissions
                    For j = 0 To arrSystemModulePermissions.Count - 1
                        ' create the module permission
                        Dim objSystemModulePermission As PermissionInfo
                        objSystemModulePermission = CType(arrSystemModulePermissions(j), PermissionInfo)
                        If objSystemModulePermission.PermissionKey = "VIEW" AndAlso permissionType = ViewPermissionType.Edit AndAlso _
                             objTabPermission.PermissionKey <> "EDIT" Then
                            'Only Page Editors get View permissions if "Page Editors Only"
                            Continue For
                        End If

                        Dim objModulePermission As ModulePermissionInfo = AddModulePermission(objModule, _
                                                                                objSystemModulePermission, _
                                                                                objTabPermission.RoleID, objTabPermission.UserID, _
                                                                                objTabPermission.AllowAccess)

                        ' ensure that every EDIT permission which allows access also provides VIEW permission
                        If objModulePermission.PermissionKey = "EDIT" And objModulePermission.AllowAccess Then
                            Dim objModuleViewperm As ModulePermissionInfo = AddModulePermission(objModule, _
                                                                                CType(arrSystemModuleViewPermissions(0), PermissionInfo), _
                                                                                objModulePermission.RoleID, objModulePermission.UserID, _
                                                                                True)
                        End If
                    Next

                    'Get the custom Module Permissions,  Assume that roles with Edit Tab Permissions
                    'are automatically assigned to the Custom Module Permissions
                    If objTabPermission.PermissionKey = "EDIT" Then
                        Dim arrCustomModulePermissions As ArrayList = objPermissionController.GetPermissionsByModuleDefID(objModule.ModuleDefID)

                        ' loop through the custom module permissions
                        For j = 0 To arrCustomModulePermissions.Count - 1
                            ' create the module permission
                            Dim objCustomModulePermission As PermissionInfo
                            objCustomModulePermission = CType(arrCustomModulePermissions(j), PermissionInfo)

                            AddModulePermission(objModule, objCustomModulePermission, _
                                                                    objTabPermission.RoleID, objTabPermission.UserID, _
                                                                    objTabPermission.AllowAccess)
                        Next
                    End If
                Next

                objModule.AllTabs = False
                objModule.Alignment = align

                'apply Custom Container to module
                objModule.ContainerSrc = CONTAINER_TRANSPARENT_PLAIN

                newModuleID = objModules.AddModule(objModule)
            Next

            Return newModuleID
        End Function

        ''' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' <summary>Adds a Module Permission</summary>
        ''' <param name="permission">The permission to add</param>
        ''' <param name="roleId">The Id of the role to add the permission for.</param>
        ''' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Private Function AddModulePermission(ByVal objModule As ModuleInfo, ByVal permission As PermissionInfo, ByVal roleId As Integer, ByVal userId As Integer, ByVal allowAccess As Boolean) As ModulePermissionInfo
            Dim objModulePermission As New ModulePermissionInfo
            objModulePermission.ModuleID = objModule.ModuleID
            objModulePermission.PermissionID = permission.PermissionID
            objModulePermission.RoleID = roleId
            objModulePermission.UserID = userId
            objModulePermission.PermissionKey = permission.PermissionKey
            objModulePermission.AllowAccess = allowAccess

            ' add the permission to the collection
            If Not objModule.ModulePermissions.Contains(objModulePermission) Then
                objModule.ModulePermissions.Add(objModulePermission)
            End If

            Return objModulePermission
        End Function

#End Region
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skin and container are determined by **SkinSrc** and **ContainerSrc** values.
These are persisted in the Tabs and TabModules tables, but you can also pass them in querystring to set a skin or container for each request.

Persistent SkinSrc value for a tab is set with **TabController** methods using **TabInfo** objects.
Respectively, use **ModuleController** and **ModuleInfo** to set ContainerSrc.
(ModuleController is also used to place modules in panes.)

Querystring parameters SkinSrc and ContainerSrc take the skin or container path value without a file extension, for example:

```
&SkinSrc=/portals/_default/skins/_default/no%20skin
&ContainerSrc=/portals/_default/containers/_default/no%20container
```

Comment: In DNN version 5.4.4 I'm using this syntax for query string parameters:
&SkinSrc=[G]Skins/MySkinFolder/MySkinPage

Comment: In version 7.3.3 looks like the syntax is instead: &SkinSrc=/PortalRoot/Portals/_default/Skins/MySkinFolder/MySkinPage