# How to fix Skin that changes when you click 'Edit' on third party DNN modules?

Tags: dotnetnuke, ctl

I have a problem where a third party module on DNN will go to a different skin when you click on 'Edit'. The edit mode changes the content on the same page with CTL in the URL. (For example: dnndev.me/Home/ctl/Manage/mid/701

This question is similar to the one asked here: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/379890/scope/posts/ctl-page-change-hide-other-modules-and-change-skin

In which Database table can I change this default skin location without uninstalling and re-installing the module?

Comment: Any URL with contains "CTL" will use the "Edit Skin" set in DNN... You can change the "Edit Skin" in the settings - But it will also change for all places the edit skin is used... Let me know if you need help setting the "Edit Skin"

Comment: Please tell me where do I set the "Edit Skin" in DNN? Isn't there a Database table which stores the Skin path for a specific module?

Comment: This link explains how to set the theme that is used for Edit / CTL Urls...
http://cooldnn.com/blog/blog-details/tabid/116/Default.aspx?BlogID=how-to-set-default-theme-in-dotnetnuke-7.x-1035

Comment: This link also may help you depending on what you're trying to achieve:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4591728/3461845

Comment: I have actually used the query-string code before which will allow customers who embed our website via an iframe to go to a different theme. I changed the default theme but it seems the Live Slider module is still using an old theme. Perhaps I need to uninstall the module but if someone has a table name which contains the themes path, then I think that would be extremely helpful.